# How to write a function that loops thru deeply nested json schema form object?

Tags: node.js, jsonschema

I'm working with json schema form objects, and we have very deeply nested ones. In order to add new features, sometimes we need to 'do the same thing' to every child object that matches certain criteria.

The root object is like

```
                        "MainApplicant": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "title": "Main Applicant",
                        "properties": {
                            "birthDetails": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "title": "Birth Details",
                                "key": "birthDetails",
                                "properties": {
                                    "dateOfBirth": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "title": "Date of Birth",
                                        "key": "dateOfBirth",
                                        "format": "date"
                                    },
                                    "countryOfBirth": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "title": "Country of Birth",
                                        "key": "countryOfBirth",
                                    },
                                },
```

It can go any number of tiers deep.

Right now im doing what i need to do by doing..

```
Object.keys(properties).forEach(function(key) {
  // console.log("dealing with key ",key,properties[key])

  if (uischema[key] == undefined) {
    uischema[key] = {}
  }
  if (properties[key].type == "object") {


    console.log(key + " is a lvl2 Object!")
    Object.keys(properties[key].properties).forEach(function(key2) {
      if (uischema[key][key2] == undefined) {
        uischema[key][key2] = {}
      }
      if (properties[key].properties[key2].type == "object") {

        // console.log(key2 + " is a lvl3 Object!",properties[key].properties[key2].properties,uischema[key])
        Object.keys(properties[key].properties[key2].properties).forEach(function(key3) {
          if (uischema[key][key2][key3] == undefined) {
            uischema[key][key2][key3] = {}
          }
          if (properties[key].properties[key2].properties[key3].type == "object") {
```

essentially, looping thru each tier manually.in this case, we're simply switching undefined to become an empty object.

its super lame but i have no idea how to write a looping function for it.

almost fell for a joke library that allows goto in javascript!

Answer (score 0):

I used recursion.Here's the code:

```
var i=0
var properties={ "MainApplicant": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "title": "Main Applicant",
                        "properties": {
                            "birthDetails": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "title": "Birth Details",
                                "key": "birthDetails",
                                "properties": {
                                    "dateOfBirth": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "title": "Date of Birth",
                                        "key": "dateOfBirth",
                                        "format": "date"
                                    },
                                    "countryOfBirth": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "title": "Country of Birth",
                                        "key": "countryOfBirth",
                                    },
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }

  function driller(data){
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key=>{

      //console.log(JSON.stringify(data[key]));
      if(typeof(data[key])==='object'){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data[key]));
        driller(data[key])
      }
    })
  }
 driller(properties)
```

And here's the output:

```
E:\Nodetest>node server.js
   {"type":"object","title":"Main Applicant","properties":{"birthDetails":{"type":"object","title":"Birth Details","key":"birthDetails","properties":{"dateOfBirth":{"type":"string","title":"Date of Birth","key":"dateOfBirth","format":"date"},"countryOfBirth":{"type":"string","title":"Country of Birth","key":"countryOfBirth"}}}}}

{"birthDetails":{"type":"object","title":"Birth Details","key":"birthDetails","properties":{"dateOfBirth":{"type":"string","title":"Date of Birth","key":"dateOfBirth","format":"date"},"countryOfBirth":{"type":"string","title":"Country of Birth","key":"countryOfBirth"}}}}

{"type":"object","title":"Birth Details","key":"birthDetails","properties":{"dateOfBirth":{"type":"string","title":"Date of Birth","key":"dateOfBirth","format":"date"},"countryOfBirth":{"type":"string","title":"Country of Birth","key":"countryOfBirth"}}}

{"dateOfBirth":{"type":"string","title":"Date of Birth","key":"dateOfBirth","format":"date"},"countryOfBirth":{"type":"string","title":"Country of Birth","key":"countryOfBirth"}}

{"type":"string","title":"Date of Birth","key":"dateOfBirth","format":"date"}

{"type":"string","title":"Country of Birth","key":"countryOfBirth"}
```